# using .next() to find a div and .append() to append back to the first?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I set up a simple JSfiddle..

http://jsfiddle.net/DbetR/

`$("div.postdata").next(".content").appendTo(".postdata");`

this is probably not working because it's trying to append it's self to it's self or something. Any ideas on how to go about this?

I want content 1 to append to the first div, and content 2 to the second.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next sibling of each `.postdata` is `<p>` element, and not `.content`. You can use something like that to make the things workable:

```
$("div.postdata").each(function() {
    $(this).nextAll(".content:first").appendTo(this);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/DbetR/2/

Comment: Thanks! I knew it had to be something simple.

Comment: Oh no, that also rearranges the <p> tags in an odd manner - I want those to stay where they are. :\

Comment: @AustinRKowitz Yeah, I've also identified that. I have updated the answer. Now it should work fine.